# Laptop temperature issue

Tags: temperature

I've tried many different flavours of Ubuntu and and all of them make my laptop's bottom hotter than Windows does. I'm running on a 3-4 years old laptop built with a i3-7100U CPU.

UPD: At idle, CPU temperature is 50 degrees. With heavier workload (viewing video, light games like Minecraft, Hotline Miami, Half-life, etc) it climbs to 60-70 degrees, and I can also feel hot air coming out of the fan lattice.

Is it Ubuntu's problem, or do i have to clean my laptop's fan and reapply thermal paste?

Comment: Could be either or both. Insufficient data.

Comment: Have you tried any of the laptop temp management tools available in the Ubuntu Software Shop?

Comment: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/95442/intel-core-i3-7100u-processor-3m-cache-2-40-ghz.html shows the T-Junction (do not exceed temp) for that CPU is 100 degrees C. Hot air from the exhaust port is normal on a laptop; it's processing, so of course it gets hotter. It it wouldn't get hot, the exhaust port would not have been engineered in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing laptop mode tools with the following command:

```
sudo apt install laptop-mode-tools
```

Then open it up from your menu and toggle settings to your liking. That fixed my heat woes with my old dell. I also found [this](https://itsfoss.com/reduce-overheating-laptops-linux/) article helpful for tools besides laptop mode tools